# Websocket in php with Apache Server SSL

Tags: php, apache, ssl, websocket, phpwebsocket

I'm searching to configure websocket in Apache web server running in php, using Devristo phpws library to run websocket worker.

When I run php file in the server it gives me this string:

```
Resource id #442015-12-22T16:41:16+00:00 NOTICE (5): phpws listening on ssl://172.31.29.79:12345
```

In front-end, build on AngularJS, I tried to established connection with:

```
var dataStream = $websocket('wss://subdomain.domain.com');
```

Google Chrome browser's console gives me this error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://subdomain.domain.com/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

I've an EC2 AWS instance where I've hosted my source code and I've configured AWS Route 53 with a record set that point to the public IP of the instance through a subdomain.

I don't know how configure a correctly reverse proxy to allow communication.

I tried to set Apache server with a Reverse Proxy, but I think I didn't configure it in the right way.

This is the configuration.
I've created a file in site-avaible calls websocket-ssl.conf and linked in site-enabled with this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName subdomain.domain.com

 ProxyPass / ssl://172.31.29.79:12345/
 ProxyPassReverse / ssl://172.31.29.79:12345/
</VirtualHost>
```

Someone can help me in this? If you want others information ask me :)

Thank you very much

Comment: Please post your apache configuration that shows your attempt at setting the reverse proxy. Also, have you looked at the apache error log?

Comment: Sure, I've edit my conf in the main question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this configuration.

- set a record CNAME calls subdomain.domain.com in AWS Route 53 that
  point to my ELB dns name;
- open port 12345 in ELB listeners;
- in front-end I established connection with:

  var dataStream = $websocket('wss://subdomain.domain.com:12345');

That's all